# Linux how to run bash script from new environment?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos, sh

How can i run a bash script from new environment?

I try to do it like this, but its not working

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/sbin:/root/bin"

racadm getsvctag > /root/Desktop/serialTest.txt
```

Comment: Make sure to save file as filename.bash.  What is the error you are getting and from which line? Try to excecute it with bash -x filename.bash so you can see what went wrong in the excecution.

Comment: PATCH? You meant PATH?

Comment: `its not working` how do you know it's "not working"? What do you mean by that. Please be more specific. Create an [MCVE] - which includes posting the actual output of your program and what do you expect your program to do.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk oh thank you, it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

The following is **not a proper solution**, but anyway, this is a way to run different version of interpreters (bash, python, php...), and make them portable. It will works on other machines of the same architecture only.

Copy the interpreter binary, in your working folder:

```
sudo cp /bin/bash .
```

Own it and make it executable:

```
sudo chmod 777 bash
```

Test script, calling the interpreter from the current dir:

```
#!./bash
echo "Hello"
// Output Hello
```

---

A better solutions with good documentation can be the tools linuxdeploy and/or appimage, this is using this method under the hood.

https://github.com/linuxdeploy/linuxdeploy

https://appimage.org/

Answer (score -2):

You can run your bash script in a new environment if you replace your shebang line with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Don't you mean instead of the `PATCH` variable the `PATH` variable?

Note: If you export your variable it will be system wide available.

Comment: The argument to `env` should be simply `bash`. Hard-coding the path is anathema to the reasons you use `env` in the first place.